# hiw push data into object of array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, arraylist, reactive

i wanna ask about how to push/replace data to objec of array of objects, sorry bout ma graamaar hehe.
this my dummy data :

```
const dummyData = {
      id: 1,
      daerah: "Bandung",
      date:"1668790800000",
      kendaraan: [
        {rodaEmpat: 50},
        {rodaDua: 22},
        {truck: 30},
        {Bus: 70},
      ]
    }, {
      id: 2,
      daerah: "Tasik",
      date:"1668877200000",
      kendaraan: [
        {rodaEmpat: 80},
        {rodaDua: 15},
        {truck: 10},
        {Bus: 50},
      ]
    },
```

then this the variable data that i want push in

```
 data: {
        
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [50, 40, 80, 19],
            backgroundColor: ["#6225E3", "#E32525", "#E7A543", "#3EAFE0"],
          },
        ],
      },
```

i want push/override data.dataSets[0].data with value of dummyData.kendaraan (this data have to using map function first), the result have to become like below :

```
data: {
        
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [50, 22, 30, 70],
            backgroundColor: ["#6225E3", "#E32525", "#E7A543", "#3EAFE0"],
          },
        ],
      },
```

thanks for your helpinggg

Answer (score 0):

```
const newArr = kendaraan.map(item => Object.values(item)[0])
//newArr = [50, 22, 30, 70]
```

it map function will help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).